# Database Management System for db-heavy, busy website/application?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, firebird

EDIT: I've learnt, and it's probably true that YouTube uses MySQL. But it probably would be the enterprise edition and not free edition. The only alternative seems to be PostgreSQL. Long question short - - `Can PostgreSQL used instead of MySQL? Is it a very good alternative in any case?`

---

Firstly, I noticed that these are the most common names when it comes to (relational) database management systems - - DB2 (IBM), Oracle Database, Microsoft SQL, Ingres, MySQL, PostgreSQL and FireBird. So, should I presume these are the best?

Okay, of the above - - `DB2 (IBM), Oracle Database and Microsoft SQL`, the so-called Enterprise DBMSs, come with a bill; while `MySQL (exclude enterprise version), PostgreSQL and FireBird` are open source and free.

As should be clear from my previous questions here, I plan to build a photo-sharing site (something like Flickr, Picasa), and like any other, it's going to be database-heavy and (hopefully) busy.

Here's what I would love to know: (1) does any one of the free DBMSs stand up to the mark with the paid enterprise DBMSs? (2) Can any of the free DBMSs scale and perform well for enormous and busy databases without too much headbanging and facepalming?

Things in my mind w.r.t the DB:

- Mature
- Fast
- Perform great/fine under heavy load
- Perform great/fine as database grows
- Scalable (smooth transition)
- support for languages (preferably Python, PHP, JS, C++)
- Feature-rich
- etc (whatever I am missing)

**PLZ NOTE:** I know Facebook, Twitter etc use (or at least used) MySQL, and I see reports from time to time, how their sysadmins cry over that decision. So, please don't say, XXX uses it, so why can't you. `They've started small, I am too. They've made mistakes, I don't want to.` I want to keep the scaling-transition smooth. I hope I am not asking too much. Thanks.

Comment: As a MySQL user, PostgreSQL is the way to go. They are fixing everything MySQL did wrong.

Comment: @Xeoncross : This could be too much, but still, let me ask for the sake of asking. Would Facebook be a lot happier with PostgreSQL as it would be with Oracle DB or MS SQL (i.e., enterprise DBMSs)?

Comment: If you could afford it, I heard Oracle owns the RDBMS field. On all the projects I have been exposed to it's either been MySQL or PostgreSQL, and of the two I would have to agree with Xeoncross.

Comment: Oracle > PostgreSQL > MySQL > MS SQL. However, only certain parts of the application need to be built on RDBMS. Much of the data can be stored on NoSQL databases (logging, text blobs, chat services, temp data, etc..).

Comment: could you substantiate your claims, xenocross?

Comment: Incidentally, it is laudable to try to learn from other people's mistakes, but one cannot be certain to avoid all technology mistakes. I think also you're worrying about this too much before you have a desirable product. Get a proposition that people will use instead of Flickr first, and you'll probably switch your technology one or twice when you grow to Flickr's size!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note as of today, MySql is not a free project aka as free as postgresql. One of the main reason why i had to switch over to PG. (Thankx to NPGSQL and PgAdmin III, it was a lot easier than it was rumoured)

However MySql does have number of advantages related to applications,addons,forums and looked good on resume.

PostgreSql is a much mature DBMS. It is a objectRDBMS. It has been around for more than 15 years. It is not known to have defaulted on any major issues. It is well known to handle transactions running in millions of rows successfully. The most important is, it's high rate of compliance with SQL standards. Infact in professional circles, it is more of an Oracle of Free RDBMS rather than MySql of popular applications.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @arvind. So do you think I can depend on PostgreSQL for a large-scale website, a photo sharing site (think as large as flickr)?

Comment: I would like to add that there are not many monitoring tools. However there is lot of information on how to tune performance of a PostgreSql server. I got lot of help from [link](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization)

Answer (score 1):

"Which is the best database" is a huge question and is the subject of much contention. I've noticed on StackOverflow there is a tendency to close such questions; although the question is interesting, it is also quite unresolvable ;-)

FWIW, I would go with this:

- Use what you know
- If it doesn't conflict too heavily with the first rule, use something that is free of charge
- Use what works with other parts of your stack
- Use what you can hire for at reasonable cost (so, maybe not Oracle unless you really have to)
- Don't optimise too early. Working slowly is *much* better than an unfinished, efficient website.

Also, scalability is not really to do with your db platform, but to do with how you design your site. Note also that some platforms scale better when adding more servers (MySQL) and others do better when increasing your server resources (PostgreSQL).

Comment: So, from the last lines, can I take that `PostgreSQL` would be the right choice?

Comment: Not necessarily. I meant that if you have a db server of a particular spec, in general MySQL does better when you add another server, and in general PostgreSQL does better if you add extra RAM or faster disks to the existing server. This is called "scale out" versus "scale up" and is a central topic of scalability.

Comment: That all said, I don't think you can go wrong if you do use PostgreSQL! I think it is a pretty great piece of technology, but then I'd be happy with MySQL too, I think.

Comment: Every website has to scale out at some point, right? So would MySQL be he only choice from the free DBMSs? Sorry if I am too ignorant, and not catching your point.

Comment: "Scale out" != "scale". "Scale out" means to scale by adding more servers, which is different of course to scaling by "scaling up" i.e. beefing up existing servers. Read the WP article on scalability for more: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability